# The structure of "come on in"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Why do two adverbs follow *come* in the phrase, ***come on in***? I know *come in*, *come on*, *go away*, but when I hear *"Come on in"* in American movies, I can't figure out its grammatical structure.

Comment: I've always interpreted it to be a subtler *forth, forward:* i.e. the same as the *on* in *he continued on* and *so on and so forth.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come on in* is the longer version of *come in.* It's an idiom as mentioned by WS2, which means proper meaning cannot be deduced from individual words. Here's the full description of this particular [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+on+in):

> Come (on) in. and come on in(to) something
>   Enter.; Come into this place. (A polite invitation to enter someone's home, office, room, etc. It is more emphatic with on.) Bob: Hello, you guys. Come on in. We're just about to start dinner. Bill: Come in. Nice to see you. Mary: I hope we're not too early. Bill: Not at all. Come on into the house and have a cold drink.

Comment: Nice definition! Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I would see it as a contraction of "come on + come in". Somehow the "Come on in" has the effect of an invitation a bit more friendly and encouraging than the short "Come in". Maybe "Come in" can evoke memories of the time one did military service.

Comment: I think that's dead on. _Come on_ -- which is common enough to have an eye spelling _c'mon_ -- and _come in_ are both frequent idioms, often appearing in exhortations and politeness formulas. _Come_ already participates in thousands of idioms, and many of them carry over with both _come on_ and _come in_; the conflation combines the chumminess of _c'mon_ with the invitation to enter of _come in_. In both the effect is to disarm the bare imperative.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known idiom, perhaps more used by Americans than in Britain, in which someone is enthusiastically welcomed into the home, or some other place.

'Come on in'.

Comment: No explanation is provided, when we say it is an "idiom".